# How can I convey going through an entire avenue when giving directions?

Tags: word-request

If I want someone to go by an entire avenue ( from the beginning to the end) to arrive to my house. What should I say?

> Go all over Benavides avenue?
>   Go all the way Benavides avenue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is understandable and acceptable

> **Go all the way down** Benavides Avenue *(until)*...

if Benavides Avenue ends e.g. a "T" junction, you could also say

> **Go to the end of** Benavides Avenue, *then*...
>   **Go down** Benavides Avenue, **until you can't go anymore**, then...

Quite often instead of "go", "follow" is used

> **Follow** Benavides Avenue **until** it ends, then...

"Go all over" would not be the correct way to express this since it may imply swerving back and forth over Benavides Avenue (all over).

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Go **all the way down** Benavides Avenue."

Couldn't find a full description of the phrase, but you can see it focused on [in this question from the English Language and Usage SE.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129677/all-the-way-down-to-phrase-with-geographical-locations)

Answer (score 0):

I think the idiomatic way to say this would be "Go the whole length of Benavides Avenue" or "Go to the end of Benavides Avenue".